# Assembly Manifest mismatch with binding redirects in place for .NET Web API 2

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've upgraded an MVC 4 & Web API project started with Visual Studio 2012 to use Web API 2 (NuGet package 5.0+).

I've added assembly manifests to redirect to the newer libraries as follows:

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

The packages are set to copy to the local bin directory on build, and I've verified that both on the local machine and the remote web server we use for testing that the correct assemblies are in the bin/ folder. No copies of the Web API libraries exist in the GAC on the remote machine.

Yet, System.Net.Http.Formatting still claims that it's not finding the correct version when a request is made to the application.

```
Could not load file or assembly System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35 or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

Can anyone explain why there are ***still*** assembly binding issues as a result of manifest mismatches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Apparently, AutoFac was attempting to use an older version of System.Web.Http (4.0.0.0). Fortunately, the creator of AutoFac recently released an updated integration package for Web API 2:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.WebApi2/

After upgrading to AutoFac.WebApi2 and removing the binding redirect for System.Net.Http.Formatting (from the original question), everything works great!